# How to get the error type of Validator on Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have something like that:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

Validator::make($data, [
   'email' => ['required', 'email']
])->validate();
```

Laravel  returns me an array like that:

```php
[
   'email' => 'The email field is required'
]
```

But what I actually want is to know that type of error it's, not only the message neither the field.

Is there any way to know the type of the error, for example, to know if the error is `email.required` or `email.email`, not only that the `email` field has an error and a message?

Comment: It's clearly stated in the error message. ```The email field is required``` obviously means that it's a ```email.required``` error.  An error message such as ```The email field must be an email``` would mean that it is a ```email.email``` error.

Comment: @Innovin Those messages can be customized, so while yes, the defaults indicate the validation check, there is the possibility for that to not be the case.

Comment: @TimLewis I see.  But beats me why one would need to know the validation type error if it is they that customized it themselves.

Comment: @Innovin I agree, but that rationale is beside the point  Imagine this is an API; an external source could consume it, and if for some reason they needed the validation check that failed, they shouldn't have to infer it from the message.

Comment: @Innovin All good! It's an edge-case, and the client shouldn't dictate what an API returns, but it was the first thing I could think of where "they" were different (i.e. the person who customized the validation vs the person who is requesting it). Cheers  Sidenote, I'm looking into it, not seeing a way to return the checks so far; `->validate()` behaves oddly)

Comment: @TimLewis I strongly believe there is no way to do that. I'm out here scratching my head.

Comment: @Innovin I'm leaning towards agreeing; I'm checking the API documentation for the MessageBag (class behind the Validation errors), not seeing anything yet: https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html

Comment: @JoãoHamerski The linked duplicate shows a way to return the specific checks that failed. You'll need to adjust your code to manually validate, like `$validator = Validator::make(...);`, then `if ($validator->fails()) { return response()->json($validator->failed(), 422); }` (or similar)

Comment: @TimLewis I was even thinking of something crazy which I don't think would work. Looping though ```request()->all()``` and validating one by one, then storing the responses in session variables. Haha would definitely not work. But I doubt if the feature the OP needs is relevant.

Comment: Nice one! What a crazy solution. Wouldn't have thought of that!

Comment: Haha yeah, an approach like that too could work, but you wouldn't want em in Session variables; that would bloat pretty quickly  A better solution is `$validator = Validator::make(...)`, then `if ($validator->fails()) { return response()->json(['failed' => $validator->failed(), 'errors' => $validator->errors()], 422); }` so that both the failed checks, and the actual errors are returned. `->validate()` basically does that, minus the `->failed()` inclusion. But yeah, the linked duplicate explains that well enough 

Comment: I need both, my custom message and the type of error, depending on the type of error I want to show a checkbox for the user, something like `if the error was from required field, do this, but only if it was required, if not do nothing`, I know I can check the message returning but the message can be easily changed, also just checking for the error type is cleaner. Thanks for your help.